# Can't Drag & Drop project folder into SimpleLESS Windows 7 64

Tags: css, less

I've downloaded SimpleLESS to use to easily compile and manage my projects' LESS CSS files. After installing, however, I'm unable to drag and drop any folder into the Drag & Drop window. Has anyone used SimpleLESS successfully on Windows 7 64 bit? The version of LESS I am using is 1.4.

Comment: My work around? I downloaded Crunch. crunchapp.net

Comment: I ran into the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just experienced the same issue on Windows 8.
Try creating a `.less` file in the folder before trying to drag and drop it inside `SimpleLESS`.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use PHPStorm, and as it turns out there's a plugin available that will handle this so no external software is needed.